# Child div jumps because the transition for parent returns wrong to initial position

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, css-transforms

I'm trying to add transition to footer div, using a hidden checkbox and a label, but when I click the label to return to original dimension and position, first it goes to top because it changes the dimension to original and then it comes to bottom. I want the div to change his dimension on bottom (slowly changing the height while being on bottom) like this example: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_transition rotated at -90deg ( minus 90 deg ).

```
     <div class="row">
         <div class="col-xsm-2-4 col-sm-3-4 col-smd-4-3 col-md-5-3 col-slg-6-3 col-lg-7-3 col-xlg-8-2">                
             <div class="article">
                <div class="inner-container dance">
                    <label for="dance"></label>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="dance" />

                    <div class="footer">
                        <div class="text pink col-xsm-2-2 col-sm-3-3 col-smd-4-3 col-md-5-4 col-slg-6-4 col-lg-7-4 col-xlg-8-4">
                            <p>Rambert</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="transparent col-xsm-2-2 col-sm-3-3 col-smd-4-3 col-md-5-4 col-slg-6-4 col-lg-7-4 col-xlg-8-4"></div>
                        <div class="sign col-xsm-2-offset-2 col-sm-3-offset-2 col-smd-4-offset-2 col-md-5-offset-2 col-slg-6-offset-2 col-xlg-7-offset-2 col-xlg-8-offset-2"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here is the css:

```
.footer { position:absolute; bottom:0; left:0; right:0; height:120px;  transition: height 0.5s ease, transform 0.5s ease; }
.text { height:120px; padding:30px; transition:all 0.5s ease; }

.transparent { height:120px; background:black; opacity:0.4; }
.sign { width:17px; height:17px; border-top:3px solid white; border-right:3px solid white; transform:rotate(45deg); bottom:50px; transition:all 0.2s; }
.inner-container { background-position:center center; background-repeat:no-repeat; position:relative; height:400px; box-sizing:border-box; overflow:hidden; }
.dance { background-image:url('http://palace.co/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/ram1.jpg'); }
label { display:none; }
label:hover { cursor:pointer; }
.dance:hover { background-image:url("http://palace.co/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/ram2.jpg"); }
.dance:hover label { position:absolute; display:block; border:10px solid white; top:0; left:0; right:0; bottom:0; z-index:2; }
#dance { display:none; }
#dance:checked ~ .footer {height:400px; }
#dance:checked ~ .footer > .transparent { position:absolute; bottom:0; right:0; }
#dance:checked ~ .footer > .text { position:absolute; height:100%; width:100%; left:0; bottom:0; z-index:1; }
```

Comment: pink class is { background:#FF627F; }

Comment: can you put this in codepen or something else and share us a link? it will be easier to check